# Deserializing XML when the root type is the same but the inner XML can represent different types

Tags: c#, xml

I have to work on a application when sends XML back. Because the root is always the "Reply", but the property's differ, deserializing can't be based on 1 object type.

I've now written code which loads the Xml first in a new XmlDocument, reads a Name attribute and based on the attribute, I try to deserialize it. Are there 
better ways?

Example xml I can expect:

```
<Reply Name="GetModulesList" Result="yes"><ModuleName="xxxxxx.exe" Path="\Debug\xxxxxxx.exe" Order="1"/></Reply>

<Reply Name="OpenRecipe" Result="yes"/>
```

How whould you solve this?

```
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(trimmedPart);
                if (doc.DocumentElement?.Attributes != null)
                {
                    XmlAttribute name = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().SingleOrDefault(a => String.Compare(a.Name, "name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
                    replyName = name?.Value;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(replyName))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetSerializerObjectType(replyName));
                    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(trimmedPart))
                    {
                        object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        if (obj != null) returnList.Add(obj);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This is a little peculiar to me. Almost always when you make a request to get some data, you need to know the format in which it is coming back. Doing this means you end up in "reflection hell" as everything you do is always going to be based on a dynamic type.

Comment: Given what you're up against, the general approach makes sense. You have to inspect it to determine which type is used to deserialize the inner part of the XML. At that step you can't avoid dealing with `object`. I'd move execution from there as quickly as possible into strongly typed code. Whatever you're doing with these replies, as soon as you know the actual type, route them to something that handles that specific type. That way the ugliness you can't avoid is isolated. However, what kind of response can someone send where the reply could be anything?

Comment: You need to use XmlReader and use XmlReaderSetting with :  settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

Comment: What I often do is wrap xml in a root : "<root>" + xml string + "</root>"

Answer (score 0):

I recently dealt with a similar scenario. Here's a *very rough* outline, adapted from what I was working with to your case as specifically as I can.

My assumption is that you're going to do different things with different types. If it's an `OpenRecipe` you're going to do one thing, if it's `GetModuleList` you're going to do something else.

The biggest difference is that each "handler" I worked with for different types might handle completely different types of data - XML, JSON, even Excel, so the handlers received content in the form of a byte array and were responsible for deserializing it. (It wasn't my idea to write an in-house version of Biztalk.)

In this case, if it's always XML, you can

- Determine the type of the inner XML from the Name attribute
- Deserialize the inner XML to that type
- Pass it off to a strongly-typed class

This class is concerned with deserializing the `Reply` (except for the unknown inner content) and passing it to something that will handle that inner content in a more strongly typed way:

```
public class XmlReplyRouter
{
    private readonly IReplyTypeMapper _replyTypeMapper;
    private readonly IHandlerFactory _handlerFactory;

    private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Reply));

    public XmlReplyRouter(
        IReplyTypeMapper replyTypeMapper,
        IHandlerFactory handlerFactory)
    {
        _replyTypeMapper = replyTypeMapper;
        _handlerFactory = handlerFactory;
    }

    public void RouteReply(string replyXml)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader(replyXml))
        {
            var reply = (Reply)_serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            var replyType = _replyTypeMapper.GetReplyType(reply.Name);
            var handler = _handlerFactory.GetHandler(replyType);
            handler.HandleReply(reply);
        }
    }
}

public class Reply
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Result { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlNode InnerXml { get; set; }

    public string XmlContent => InnerXml?.OuterXml;
}
```

That's where all the ugliness goes.
The `XmlAnyElement` attribute allows us to deserialize without knowing what to make of that inner content. Once we know what type to use we can separately deserialize that.

The implementations of `IReplyTypeMapper` and `IHandlerFactory` could be anything. In my case I couldn't use a DI container so it contained a `Dictionary<string, IReplyHandler>` and selected the correct one based on the name. (The terminology I worked with was different, but same concept.)

The first determines the type (from the "name" attribute) and the second returns a handler for that type.

```
public interface IReplyTypeMapper
{
    Type GetReplyType(string replyName);
}

public interface IHandlerFactory
{
    IReplyHandler GetHandler(Type contentType);
}
```

Finally, here's the interface and a base class for the reply handlers. 
As you can see, the base class doesn't really do anything. It just bridges the gap between `object` and generic types so that we can write strongly-typed handlers.

```
public interface IReplyHandler
{
    void HandleReply(object content);
}

public abstract class BaseHandler<T> : IReplyHandler
{
    private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    public void HandleReply(object content)
    {
        HandleReplyContent((T)content);
    }

    protected abstract void HandleReplyContent(T content);
}
```

As you can see it's very similar to what you're doing. The objective, though, is that once I've gotten this minimal amount of initial code out of the way, everything else is a strongly-typed class like this:

```
public class SomeSpecificReplyHandler : BaseHandler<SomeSpecificReply>
{
    // Maybe these have dependencies of their own. That's easiest if 
    // everything gets resolved from an IoC container.
    protected override void HandleReplyContent(SomeSpecificReply content)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

I don't know if this might be overkill for your needs. My intent was to start from an entry point where my data could be just about anything and quickly get out of there to a place where all of my code was strongly-typed and easy to test. All of these classes are testable (I wrote a few while typing this up) the individual handlers would also be easy to test.

[This post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/12/16/liberation-of-pure-di-mef-is-not-ioc.html) contains some other details about implementing the factories without an IoC container. In my case I couldn't work with an IoC container, so I had to "manually" compose all of my classes. The inner implementation of the factory was just a dictionary. That way if I had the option of switching to an IoC container later I could replace the whole thing with DI registrations.